# converting floating type to floating type in haskell

Tags: haskell

```
doubles :: Floating -> Floating
doubles  =  (0.1 + 1.1) - 1.2
```

i receive this error in Haskell

```
• Expecting one more argument to ‘Floating’
      Expected a type, but ‘Floating’ has kind ‘* -> Constraint’
    • In the type signature: doubles :: Floating -> Floating
   |
32 | doubles :: Floating -> Floating 
   |                        ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: `Floating` is *not* a type, `Floating` is a typeclass, a "group" of types. You thus should add a type constraint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`Floating`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Floating) is *not* a type, `Floating` is a typeclass, a "group" of types, for example `Float` and `Double` are "members" of this typeclass. You thus should add a type constraint:

```
doubles :: Floating a => a
doubles = (0.1 + 1.1) - 1.2
```

This thus means that for every type `a` where `a` is a member of the `Floating` typeclass, this function is defined.

The type is `Floating a => a` not `Floating => a -> a`, since there is no input: `doubles` is a *constant*.